# Define layout for screen with size 5″ - 7″

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to define different layouts specifically for screens  with size 5 - 7 inches. How can I do that?

For example: for screens with size more than 7 inches, I defined the layouts in the `layout-sw6000dp` folder. How can I do the same for screens  with size 5 - 7 inches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in layout-large, and use dp as the units for dimensions.

Large is defined as 4.5-7 inches:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

You could also change from using layout-sw600dp to layout-xlarge for your >7 inch layouts.

Comment: Actually, my layout displays well for screen with size<5" ... but not for >5"and <7" ...Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'll need more detail. What are the density and screen sizes of these <5" devices where it's working well?

Comment: what I can tell from my experience is that it is displaying fine till Galaxy S3 and nexus 4.. but not note 2

Comment: The S3 and N4 are both classed as normal sized (i.e. layout-normal), whereas the Note 2 will be large (i.e. layout-large).

Comment: so you mean.. i put those layouts in layout-large?? i wonder if this conflict with some other devices..

Comment: Yes, I mean go with my original answer because the S3 and N4 won't be affected. Yes there may be conflicts, but they'll at least work because they'll use the layout-large.