# Phone and tablet support for button spacing on the layout view

Tags: android

I have the following layouts in my Android project. Because, I want to support the view for different size android devices and tabs.

```
layout-large
layout-normal
layout-small
layout-xlarge
```

In App Gradle, it has been set from min. 9 - 22.

When I am testing on 5 inch phones, 7 inch tablets and less than 5 inch phones, I am seeing for 5 inch phone and 7 inch tablet, it uses always “layout-large”, thus there are 2 buttons placed centre of the screen horizontally doesn’t give proper spacing in Tablet, it shows with proper spacing in 5 inch phone as expected. Could you please advise me how to take care of the button spacing in the layout to support 5 inch phone and 7 inch layout with single layout. Looking around, there are so many suggestions and confusing a lot…When I looked at android link, [Android developer link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) couldn’t understand much.

layout-large.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="70px"
        android:id="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
        android:onClick="doClick"
        android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="169dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="70px"
        android:id="@+id/StopButton"
        android:onClick="stopAudio"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATED:

I am asking my question even more simple. I have 3.2 inch phone, 4.2 inch phone, 4.3 inch phone, 4.5 inch phone, 5 inch phone and one 7 inch tablet/ I want to support my app in all these devices mandatorily. I have set min 9 max 22 in gradle. What should i do now for creating 'layout' and 'drawable' folders? I am getting confused seeing links in android and other forum links. I am having Relative Layout in all the layouts and it set with match_parent of width and height. Should I even set static width and height here? –  Stella just now

Comment: Check out [Android Developer Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)  and [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15039367/2032561)

Answer (score 0):

For different layouts for different screen sizes, try naming your layout folder something like `layout-sw600dp` instead of `layout-large`.

> Could you please advise me how to take care of the button spacing in the layout to support 5 inch phone and 7 inch layout with single layout.

Try having a dimension declared (`<dimen name="dimenName">30dp</dimen>`) in both `values/dimens.xml` and `values-sw600dp/dimens.xml` with appropriate values and accessing them with `@dimen/dimenName` in your layout.

If you need more help, post some screenshots of the problem. You should also try to use `dp` units instead of `px`.

Comment: I have first doubt, what will make difference if i use layout-sw600dp instead of layout-large? What should i do with other folders layout-normal
layout-small and layout-xlarge?

Comment: @Stella ipavl's response is correct. All the info you need is in the documentation though. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Stella basically layout-normal/small/large... etc was the old, imprecise way of supporting different screen sizes, layout-swXXXdp is the way to go since 3.x

Comment: I agree. My question is, If set layout-sw600dp for 7 inch tablet then what layout should i keep for phones , I am confused with android.developer links? I'll ask simple question, i want to support 3.2 inch phone to till 7 inch tablet. How should make layout and drawable folders ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone#Platform) only 6.8% devices are below API 4.0.3 and according to [Screen Sizes and Densities](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone#Screens) only 4.4% have smaller than normal sized screens.

- So you can **DELETE** `layout-small` folder and make your
  `minSdkVersion` as **14**.
- Now you can start using new **size group** for making layouts, i.e. `sw<N>dp`.

As quoted [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

> The reason designing for 7" tablets is tricky when using the generalized size groups is that a 7" tablet is technically in the same group as a 5" handset (the large group). While these two devices are seemingly close to each other in size, the amount of space for an application's UI is significantly different, as is the style of user interaction.

You need to define different layouts for 5" and 7" devices, so you should make layout for 7" in `layout-sw600dp` folder and rest everything can go in `layout` folder (unless you make `layout-sw720dp` for 10 inch tablets).

If you still need layout for 5" devices and <5" devices to be different, try making `layout-large` for the **5" devices** and just `layout` for **<5" devices**.

Comment: I am asking my question even more simple. I have 3.2 inch phone, 4.2 inch phone, 4.3 inch phone, 4.5 inch phone, 5 inch phone and one 7 inch tablet/ I want to support my app in all these devices mandatorily. I have set min 9 max 22 in gradle. What should i do now for creating 'layout' and 'drawable' folders? I am getting confused seeing links in android and other forum links. I am having Relative Layout in all the layouts and it set with match_parent of width and height. Should I even set static width and height here? How do I know setting "layout" for other phones what should be the "DP" ?

Comment: Another question is, if I keep "layout-large", can the resources automatically be used for 5 inch phones? if I keep "layout", can resources automatically be taken for <5 inch phones? if I keep "layout-sw600dp", can resources automatically be taken for 7 inch tab?

Comment: `layout` will work for 3.2", 4.2", 4.3" and 4.5". Try same with 5" also if it doesn't look good add `layout-large` for 5". `layout-sw600dp` is necessary for 7". Similarly you can distinguish between `drawables` folder.
<br>You can also see ---> If the layout doesn't need some specified width (in DP) for items, you can use `LinearLayout` and `weight`, they help to make very complex layout look same across all screens.

Comment: Ok, But when I used  "layout", "layout-large", "layout-small", "layout-sw600dp" and "layout-large", I found for 4.5 inch phone it has been taken "layout-large" resources, not the "layout"

Comment: I haven't checked with so many devices, that was a general interpretation of what I read in one of the links given in my answer.. it was quoted 5" uses `layout-large`, anyways as you said you can use `layout-large` for 4.5" and 5". But after defining `layout-sw600dp`, 7" will take from that only as sw600dp = smallest with 600dp which is not found for any device <7".

Comment: OK. Sorry I wrote wrongly, I found 4.5 inch phone takes resources from layout-normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75925/discussion-between-ankit-bansal-and-stella).

Comment: I kept Relative Layout width and height as match_parent. Hope this should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make folder just drawable and then put all image in this.It is general folder for all types. Then you can take your button in relative layout and set button center horizontal=true and set height and width with fill parent and set margin left and right 20dp for set in center.